# Guardar varios datos a la vez en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, rutas, controller

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto de laravel en el cual necesito guardar varios datos a la vez, estuve investigando un poco sobre como hacerlo, y vi que podia hacerlo en un foreach dentro de las funciones del controlador, la cosa es que a mi no me funciona, y no se si tengo algun problema en mi ruta o en mi propio controlador, ya que al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

"**Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\DatoshojaController::finalcheck(), 1 passed in C:\Users\GJLH8A\Desktop\prueba\pruebaproyecto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected**"

A continuacion adjunto mi codigo:

Archivo blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="vistas">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img src="/images/R.png" alt="" id="logoborg">
                <a href="/logout" class="btn" id="b3">Cerrar sesion</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-responsive" align="center">
            <form action="{{route('finalcheck')}}" method="POST">
            <table class="table table-success table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="33" class="table-secondary">
                                <p align="center">Al inicio del turno</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach ($registros as $key=>$registro)
                            @if ($registro->turno == '5-7' &&
                                $registro->documentoid == 'F7-SETCS-ELE-CR-L1-01' &&
                                $registro->partetabla == 'AL INICIO DE TURNO')
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $registro->criterio }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d1]" id="d1">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d2]" id="d2">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d3]" id="d3">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d4]" id="d4">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d5]" id="d5">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>            
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public function check(Request $request)
    {
        $options = option::all();
        $registros = Registro::all();
        return view('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-20-L1-01.check')
        ->with('registros',$registros)
        ->with('options',$options);
    }

    public function finalcheck(Request $request, $id)
    {
        foreach($request->registro as $key=>$value)
        {
            $registros = Registro::find($value['id']);
            if($registros)
            {
                $registros->d1 = $value['d1'];
                $registros->d2 = $value['d2'];
                $registros->d3 = $value['d3'];
                $registros->d4 = $value['d4'];
                $registros->d5 = $value['d5'];
                $registros->save();
            }
        }
        return redirect ('/F7-SETCS-ELE-CR-L1-01-57');    
    }
```

Rutas:

```
Route::get('/check',[DatoshojaController::class,'check'])->name('check');
Route::put('/finalcheck',[DatoshojaController::class,'finalcheck'])->name('finalcheck');
```

Comment: ¿porque tienes definida la función de este modo? `finalcheck(Request $request, $id)`... no parece que vayas a usar el `$id` dentro de ella. Si lo borras creo que al menos ese error lo superas.

Comment: @masterguru se supone que el `id` me va a ayudar a recorrer mi arreglo de valores, ya hice la modificacion en la ruta para que me funcione de esa forma, pero pues como tu lo mencionas, solo es un error, sigo buscando aun que mas hacer para que se establezca todo correctamente, al menos de la parte del `id` , ya lo pase

Comment: Si necesitas un `id` seguramente debes ponerlo dentro del `<form></form>` en forma de `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="VALOR">` donde VALOR debería ser el código PHP necesario para incorporarlo a ese atributo `value`.  De este modo cuando lo envias lo recibes dentro del `$request` y lo puedes usar.  El caso es que no veo el `name="id"` en ninguna parte de tu formulario y entiendo que lo necesitas.

Comment: @masterguru si, es lo que acabo de hacer, como te menciono, esa parte ya la solucione, pero no he puesto respuesta porque aun necesito acomodar otras cosas, igual gracias por tu observacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de realizar ciertos cambios, lo pude acomodar a como me resulto mejor para mi.

Primero, en las rutas le envio el valor id, para que coincida con el id requerido en el controlador:

```
Route::get('/check',[DatoshojaController::class,'check'])->name('check');
Route::put('/finalcheck{id}',[DatoshojaController::class,'finalcheck'])->name('finalcheck');
```

Despues, en mi vista blade, añado un input oculto con el valor de id, esto con el objetivo de que me tome dicho id y no tenga problemas al momento de pasar el valor, con ello ya quedaria solucionado el problema, asi como tambien hice modificaciones para que me muestre el valor que tiene mi select en la base de datos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="vistas">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img src="/images/R.png" alt="" id="logoborg">
                <a href="/logout" class="btn" id="b3">Cerrar sesion</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-responsive" align="center">
            <table class="table table-success table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="33" class="table-secondary">
                                <p align="center">Al inicio del turno</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach ($registros as $key=>$registro)
                        <form action="{{route('finalcheck')}}" method="POST">
                            @if ($registro->turno == '5-7' &&
                                $registro->documentoid == 'F7-SETCS-ELE-CR-L1-01' &&
                                $registro->partetabla == 'AL INICIO DE TURNO')
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="{{$registro->id}}" name="registro[{{$key}}][id]">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $registro->criterio }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d1]" id="d1">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d2]" id="d2">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d3]" id="d3">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d4]" id="d4">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="registro[{{$key}}][d5]" id="d5">
                                            @foreach ($options as $option)
                                                <option value="{{ $option['opcion'] }}">{{ $option['opcion'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>            
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Por la parte del controlador, permanece igual.